# Homology group of the complement of an euclidean space and its subspace

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm considering the following question - if M is an m-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then how to compute the homology of $\mathbb{R}^n - M$.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you do the cases $\mathbb R^3 - \{ \rm point \}$, $\mathbb R^3 - \mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^3 - \mathbb R^2$? [Hint: Convince yourself that these spaces deformation-retract onto $S^2$, $S^1$ and $S^0$ respectively.] Can you see how this idea generalises?

Comment: What is $\mathbb R^n -M $  deformation retract onto?

Comment: Thank you both @KennyWong. But I still don't quite get this... Is $M$ always homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^k$? And is $\mathbb{R}^n - M$ deformation retract onto $S^{n - k - 1}$?